# maximum consecutive repetition in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to count the maximal consecutive trues in the array. In the follows, it return me 4. It seems that all the trues in the array are added up. What's wrong with my work? Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
int maxCount = 0;
bool list[7];
list[0] = true;
list[1] = true;
list[2] = false;
list[3] = false;
list[4] = true;
list[5] = true;
list[6] = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (list[i]==true)
    {
        count++;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (list[j]== list[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > maxCount)
    {
        maxCount = count;
    }
}
cout << maxCount << endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't need O(n*n) algo. Same can be achieved in O(n).
Also, `list` is a built-in container in `std` namespace. Since you're using `cout`, which is also in `std`, you might consider renaming your array!

Answer (score 1):

The way you are implementing is completely wrong. You are adding all the `true` entries in the array, without accounting for a `false` in between.

Do this:

```
int currentCount = 0, maxCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    // arr is the name of the array
    if(arr[i])    ++currentCount;
    else    currentCount = 0;  // resetting to zero if false encountered
    maxCount = ( (currentCount > maxCount) ? currentCount : maxCount );
}
cout << maxCount << endl;
```

Comment: ternary can be replaced by `maxCount = std::max(maxCount, count);`.

Comment: Yes that's a possibility too.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to consider the relationship between `count` and `maxCount` again.

```
int maxCount = 0;
int count = 0;
int size = sizeof(list) / sizeof(bool);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (list[i]==true) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (count > maxCount) {
    maxCount = count;
}
cout << maxCount << endl;
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/0kJ7hF)

Answer (score 0):

Break on true/false changes and be careful of only last true

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int maxCount = 0;
    bool list[7];
    list[0] = true;
    list[1] = true;
    list[2] = false;
    list[3] = false;
    list[4] = true;
    list[5] = true;
    list[6] = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // be careful last true
    {
       int count = 0;
       if (list[i]==true)
       {
           count++;
           for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
           {
               if (list[j]== list[i])
               {
                   count++;
               }
               else
               {
                   break; // true / false transition
               }
           }
        }
        if (count > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    cout << maxCount << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should traverse the array just **once**, but using **two** counters:

- First for current streak of true values
- Second for highest streak

Every time you encounter a **false** reset the current streak counter to zero, and every time you encounter a **true**, increment the value of current streak and check whether it's higher than highest streak counter, and if so, update it.